# SQL - INSERT statement with BIT conversion

Tags: sql, excel, ssis, insert-statement

There is an INSERT statement in SQL that I am working on - See query below.
When I run the statement, it gives this error:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 2
>   String or binary data would be truncated.
>   The statement has been terminated.

How do I rectify this error?

In the Old table (Where the data is coming from),
the [Environment] column is called [Err_Dev_Prod],
and it is an NVARCHAR (50) datatype. In the new table
it is  BIT datatype

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'LCN_Board', N'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE LCN_Board
CREATE TABLE [LCN_Board](
    [Metric_Id] VARCHAR(128) NULL,
    [Environment] BIT NULL, --[Err_Dev_Prod]
    [Date/Time] DATETIME NULL,
    [IMPORT_DATE] DATE DEFAULT GETDATE() NULL,
    [MODIFIED_DATE] DATE DEFAULT GETDATE() NULL,
    [REPORTING_PERIOD]DATE NULL,
    [Process_ID] Uniqueidentifier DEFAULT (NEWID()) NOT NULL,
    [Key] VARCHAR(128) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT INTO LCN_Board
(   [Metric_Id], 
    [Environment], 
    [Date/Time], 
    [IMPORT_DATE], 
    [MODIFIED_DATE], 
    [REPORTING_PERIOD],
    [Process_ID]
    )
SELECT  
    [Metric Id], 
    CASE LOWER([Err_Dev_Prod]) WHEN 'yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    [Date/Time], 
    [IMPORT_DATE], 
    [MODIFIED_DATE], 
    [REPORTING_PERIOD],
    [Process_ID] 
FROM dbo. LCN_Board_old
ORDER BY [Date/Time];
GO
```

Comment: try using true and false instead of 1 and 0

Comment: It doesn't looks like bit field and its conversion causing this error. More likely you have old table `Metric Id` or `Process_ID` field size greater than `VARCHAR(128)`

Comment: Please post the complete definition of both the tables `LCN_Board_old` and `LCN_Board`

Comment: This is the complete Old table                                                                                                       CREATE TABLE [LCN_Board_old](
     [Metric_Id] NVARCHAR(255) NULL,
     [Description] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
     [Error found in Development or Production?] NVARCHAR (50)NULL,
     [Date/Time] DATETIME NULL,
     [IMPORT_DATE] DATE DEFAULT GETDATE() NULL,
     [MODIFIED_DATE] DATE DEFAULT GETDATE() NULL, 
     [REPORTING_PERIOD] NVARCHAR (50)NULL,
     [Process_ID] Uniqueidentifier DEFAULT (NEWID()) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: Hello Andy Korneyev,                                                                                                  So, do I do that in a SELECT statement or do I have to build a package? If it is a  statement, how do I formulate it? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is not the case of BIT conversion,try to increase the varcahar limit or set to max if possible